# How to insert default value in the comma separated strings?

Tags: javascript

I have group of comma separated strings and if any string is not a numeric value, I need to insert "(1)".

```
"stack(2),flow,over(4),temp(7)"  Here insert default value to flow(1)
"stack(2),flow(3),over(4),temp"  Here insert default value to temp(1)
"stack,flow(3),over,temp"        Here insert default value to stack(1),over(1),temp(1)
```

I have validation code to validate and insert default values where needed. Please help me how to insert a default value within parentheses.

javascript function :

```
var case1 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(7)"; // - true
var case2 = "stack(2),flow(3),over(4),temp(k)"; // - false
var case3 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4),temp(0"; // - false
var case4 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(,temp)"; // - false
var case5 = "stack(2),flow(2),over(4)temp(8)"; // - false
var case6 = "stack(1),flow(7),over,temp"; // - true
var case7 = "stack(1),flow(7),OVER,Temp"; // - true
var case8 = "stack(1),flow(7),over_r,temp_t"; // - true

function testCases(str)
{
    var pattern = /^[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?(?:,[a-z]+(?:\(\d+\))?)*$/
    return pattern.test(str);
}
```

The above function works for validation in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zm375/)

Comment: What if `"stack1"` or `"stack1)"`? Should we replace by either `"stack(1)"` or `"stack1(1)"`?

Comment: "stack1(1)" is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Use `String.prototype.split` and `String.prototype.join` to process each part of your string.

#### Details

If you want to apply custom fixes to your string, you need to split it in several parts and then process them. Once the job is done, concat all the parts together.

#### Implementation

Using `Array.prototype.map` (**Warning:** not compatible with IE 8 and below):
[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ooflorent/LEXXR/).

```
function testCases(str) {
  return str.split(',').map(function(s) {
    if (s.match(/^[a-z]+\(\d+\)$/i)) {
      // string is valid
      return s;
    } else {
      // you can do processing here based on the failure reason
      return s + '(1)';
    }
  }).join(',');
}
```

Using a `for` loop (IE8-compatible):

```
function testCases(str) {
  var parts = str.split(',');
  var i = parts.length;
  while (i--) {
    var s = parts[i];
    if (!s.match(/^[a-z]+\(\d+\)$/i)) {
      // string is invalid
      // you can do processing here based on the failure reason.
      parts[i] = s + '(1)';
    }
  }
  return parts.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner than mine!

Comment: Good, but these won't support IE8 because it has map method.

Comment: @user2848031 A simple `for` loop or a polyfill would do the job!

Comment: @user2848031 Added an IE8-compatible version

Comment: Can I suggest `return s.match(/^[a-z]+\(\d+\)$/i)) ? s : s + '(1)';` instead of the `if`? :)

Comment: @gnclmorais That's what I've done before but there may be more than one solution depending on the failure reason (e.g. `case3`, `case4` and `case5` need another treatment).

Comment: @Florent, I see... Well, you could always improve it by having a single `return` statement, instead of two. :)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't have lookbehinds - they'd be very useful here. Instead, we have to cheat:

```
str = str.replace(/([^)])(,|$)/g,"$1(1)$2");
```

What this does is capture whatever character comes before the comma or end of string, provided it is not a close-parenthesis. It then inserts the `(1)` default value in that position.

Comment: As an aside, a replacement with lookbehind would look something like this: `/(?<!\))(?=,|$)/g,'(1)'`

Comment: Beautiful, I love your solution.

Comment: It supports lookaheads though : `.replace(/([^)])(?=,|$)/g, '$1(1)')` :)

Comment: @gnclmorais What does OP want?

Comment: Original Poster, the author of the question.

Comment: Argh, sorry, my bad. 
From what I understand, the OP wants to place `(1)` __only__ after words/string, i.e., it should not place `(1)` after `temp)` or `temp(0`, as you can see by his jsfiddle example.

Comment: @gnclmorais There is nothing about that.

Comment: @wared, check his jsfiddle example and his comments about `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var add_default = function(str, def) {
    str = str.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        if(!/\(\d+\)$/.test(str[i]))
            str[i] += "(" + def + ")";
    }
    return str.join(',');
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BhVx3/3/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution :

```
function fix(input) {
    var r = /^(.*?)(?:\((\d*)\)?|\)?)$/,
        input = input.split(','),
        output = [],
        item;
    while (item = input.shift()) {
        item = item.match(r);
        item = item[1] + '(' + (item[2] || 1) + ')';
        output.push(item);
    }
    return output.join();   
}
```

```js
var s = 'stack(2),over(4),flow,hello(0,kitty2)';
s = fix(s); // "stack(2),over(4),flow(1),hello(0),kitty2(1)"
```